# Switch to the tab that sent the notification when the notification is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

Let's say I have a site and it sends a notification in the background while the tab is still open. How do I have the browser switch to my tab if the user clicks on my notification using JavaScript (pure, no jQuery)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). In your code, after you create the notification, you'll want to add an `onclick` event and tell it to focus on the tab (rather than the browser).

```
let notification = new Notification('Test Notification'});
notification.onclick = function () { 
    window.parent.parent.focus();
};
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Notification_events), you can also use the `addEventListener()` method instead of `onclick` if you like.

Comment: Note: `window.parent === window`, so `window.focus();` would be sufficient. Also important to know is that the browser silently ignores the focus call if it's not directly triggered from the notification's click event handler.